# Maven - why can't I override the version of a dependencyManagement imported pom?

Tags: java, maven

I'm looking for an explanation about this case: I have a project that has a dependencyManagement / dependencies section with:

**myproject/pom.xml:**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.M3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The **spring-cloud-starter-parent pom** defines:

```
<properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <spring-cloud-netflix.version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud-netflix.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-netflix.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This way, my project will get spring-cloud-starter-eureka version 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.

I was expecting that if I add in myproject/pom.xml a properties section with another version I would override the default version, however it is ignored, why?

**myproject/pom.xml**

```
...
<properties>
        <spring-cloud-netflix.version>1.0.0</spring-cloud-netflix.version>
</properties>
...
```

Comment: Are you correctly using the `http://repo.spring.io/milestone` repo?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I cannot override the version of that specific jar

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The property `spring-cloud-netflix.version` has already been resolved when building the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka` artifact, so you can not just override this when declaring the dependency.

To properly specify a certain dependency version, you have to add the version of that dependency in the `dependencyManagement` section of your pom:

```
...
<properties>
        <spring-cloud-netflix.version>1.0.0</spring-cloud-netflix.version>
</properties>
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.M3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-netflix.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As a best practice for a multi module build you would typically have a shared master pom containing the `dependencyManagement` settings incl. all version information for all your dependencies.

Comment: Hi Torsten, thanx for your answer. My proyect already has a parent pom and can successfully override the variables defined there. What I didn't understand is why I can override the variables from the parent project's dependencyManagement, and not the ones from myproject's dependency-management-imported pom.

Comment: You cannot configure the content of your dependencies, you can only switch between different versions of them. If you do not like the versions of dependencies the parent pom defines you have to provide alternate versions of your dependencies in your project to override those.

Comment: This by itself is an understandable situation, however, what's weird is that it's still possible to override the version on the command-line, like so: `-Dspring-cloud-netflix.version=...` That's very unintuitive once you've accepted the former.